# Dimension of the kernel of $\tilde{f}\otimes\tilde g$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I have the following problem I'm struggling with :

Let $E,F,G,H$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces.
Let $u \in \mathcal L(E,G)$ and $v \in \mathcal L(F,H)$ ( s.t $\mathcal L(E,G)$ is the linear mapping $E \rightarrow G$) .

I have to find the image of $u \otimes v $, I found in my lecture something really useful the following statement :
$$\mathcal L(E,G) \otimes \mathcal L(F,H) \simeq \mathcal L(E\otimes F,G\otimes H) $$

So we can say that the image of : $u\otimes v \in \mathcal L(E\otimes F,G\otimes H) $ is $\tilde{f}(E)\otimes\tilde g(F)$ , here is where I have some trouble :

> Using the rank of $u\otimes v$ (and also the dimension of the spaces), find the dimension of the kernel of $\tilde{f}\otimes\tilde g$.

**EDIT:**

Using the comments, here is an edit :

We suppose that :
$\dim(u(E)) = n  \;$ and $\; \dim(v(E))= n' \;$ , $\dim(E)=k $  , $\dim(F)=k'$

Hence we have :
$ \dim $(($u\otimes v)(E \otimes F) = \dim (u(E) \otimes v(F))= n n'=\dim (\Im(u\otimes v))$

$\dim(E\otimes F)= kk'$

The rank-nullity theorem states that :

$\dim(\Im(u\otimes v)) \;- \dim(E\otimes F) =\dim(\ker(u\otimes v)$ , so

$\dim(\ker(u\otimes v)= nn'-kk'$

Comment: Well, for vector spaces $V$ and $W$, if $dim(V)=n$ and $dim(W)=m$, then $dim(V \otimes W)=nm$. If you know the dimensions of the images of $u$ and $v$, can you figure out the dimension of the image of $u \otimes v$? Your answer will also tell you the dimension of the kernel

Comment: Hello @leibnewtz , thanks for your comment I didn't know for $\dim(V \otimes W)$. How can I try to figure out the rank of $u \otimes v $ is there a little statement or something useful?

Comment: (Can we say that if $u,v$ onto, it implies that $u\otimes v$ also onto)?

Comment: We can definitely say that. The reason why is that the tensor product is generated by simple tensors, so it suffices to show that every simple tensor is in the image.

Comment: Alright thank you very much, but I still have no clue for the dimension of the image of $u\otimes v$ , any other hint ?

Comment: Why do you switch between $u,v$ and $\tilde f,\tilde g$?

Comment: The point is that
$$
\dim((u \otimes v)(E \otimes F)) = \dim(u(E) \otimes v(F)) = \dim(u(E)) \otimes \dim(v(F))
$$

Comment: Just before this question we had to prove that the image of $u \otimes v$ is $\tilde f(E) \otimes \tilde g(F)$ , and then we had to find the rank of $u\otimes v$ , to find the dimension of the kernel of $\tilde f(E) \otimes \tilde g(F)$  (It's written this way in the lecture does it change anything ?)

Comment: @JGuyvm Ben Grossmann's comment is all you need to solve the problem

Comment: I've made an edit , can you see if it's correct ?

Comment: @leibnewtz sorry to bother again but I don't see why exactly the image of $u\otimes v \in \mathcal L(E\otimes F,G\otimes H) $ why it's not  $\in G\otimes G$

Comment: Hello @JGuyvm don't forget that $\dim(\Im u) = dim (u(E)) $=  rank $u$